# Fetch data over the web: curl, file_get_contents or something else?

Tags: developer

I've written quite a few extensions that need a way to fetch data from the web. Sometimes I've used `file_get_contents` sometimes cURL, other times I've sucked in (geddit!) [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). Each of those has it's own requirements.

Just want to check that CiviCRM does not offer a service/wrapper for this that knows what is available? What's recommended?

Comment: great question. I am wondering in there is a more definitive answer in 2021: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/xgehp38t7ig88gg5soob3wua1y

Comment: are there dev docs or a module that uses CiviCRM's Guzzle which would be useful to an extension author as a reference? the example I found when I looked said `// currently not working` so I won't link to it here!

Comment: @ChrisBurgess I don't think Civi needs a copy of [Guzzle's docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/6.5/)?

Comment: true :) [example](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5db0bc3c1f54eaca4307f103a73bda596ae914d6/CRM/Utils/Check/Component.php#L134-L145)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CiviCRM core has bundled in Guzzle for a few years now (this was an old issue that got highlighted just now) - so Guzzle is the recommended approach

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: **See Eileen's updated answer above, this is now outdated.**

As of 2021 CiviCRM bundles Guzzle!

---

I'm unsure what's *recommended*, but there are several patterns (at least) through the codebase:

- [`CRM_Utils_HttpClient`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d799e82070e2319bb5b2e580fabf90f64f907010/CRM/Utils/HttpClient.php), used in core functionality like system checks. This has test coverage!
- PHP [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), common in the payment processors.
- PEAR HTTP_Request, in older code like [geocoders](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/294ea01475fbdce67534f6759307c80e19fad497/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Yahoo.php).
- Occasionally [`file_get_contents()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/648631cd94799e87fe2347487d465b1a7256aa57/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Security.php#L335) to switch things up for fun?

Comment: I downvoted this because it was the right answer at the time but 2021 !== 2018